# selectOneMenu Default value issue with converter

Tags: java, jsf-2, converters, selectonemenu

I am binding selectOneMenu value to list of strings and putting converter to convert the string value to list and the list to string but that cause problem with default value as it's not selected.

JSF Code:-

```
<h:selectOneMenu
        value="#{property.values}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{tags.select_one}"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItems value="#{property.enums}"></f:selectItems>
        <f:converter converterId="listConverter" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

converter Code:-

```
public class ListConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        if (arg2 == null)
            return null;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(arg2);
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        if (arg2 instanceof List)
            if (!((List<String>) arg2).isEmpty())
                return ((List<String>) arg2).get(0);
            else
                return null;
        return (String) arg2;
    }

}
```

when there is value in list the selected value still the first item which is select_one.

Comment: value in `h:selectOneMenu` should be String. Check if `property.values` return String and it is really place where you store selected value (from your list).

Comment: it's list of string and with converter i convert it to string